# Segmentation fault 11 error on such simple code?

Tags: c++

I am very new to C++...
I'm trying to implement a simple stack with Linked List..I know segmentation fault has to do with memory but all I did was make a stack with one element in it and it's only throwing "Segmentation fault: 11"  that I have no clue where it came from. Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Node{
     int data;
     struct Node* link;
 };

Node* Push(int, Node*);

int main(){
    struct Node* top = nullptr;
    top = Push(3, top);
}

Node* Push(int data,  Node* top){
    struct Node* temp = (struct Node*) new Node();
    temp->data = data;
    temp->link = top->link;
    top = temp;
    return top;
}
```

Comment: struct Node* top = nullptr; why do you point to a nullptr, I think this could cause your error

Comment: In C++ you can write `struct Node* temp = (struct Node*) new Node();` as `Node* temp = new Node();`. And in `top->link` you're dereferencing a null pointer leading to **undefined behavior**.

Comment: In `temp->link = top->link;` called through `top = Push(3, top);` in `main` you dereference a null pointer.

Comment: If `top` is `nullptr`, then this will cause a segfault: `temp->link = top->link;` You are dereferencing a null pointer there with `top->link`. You need to check first if `top` is a null pointer, and not do this when it is.

Comment: *I have no clue*. There two possibilities here, either you still have a lot to learn about pointers, or you aren't looking at the code you wrote properly. I suspect it's mostly the latter. It's obvious to anyone else looking at the code that `top->link` is the problem, but you've convinced yourself that the code you wrote is correct, and you can't shake that conviction no matter how many times you look at your own code.

Comment: Incidentally (no one seems to have mentioned this) the correct code is `temp->link = top;`.